# How to refresh Image View load from URL on Button click?

Tags: android

How to re-load Image View from URL on button click?

What I have tried is, in Main Activity

```
makeImageRequest();

btnImageReq.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
         makeImageRequest();
    }
});
```

And my custom method to load image,

```
private void makeImageRequest() {
    ImageLoader imageLoader = AppController.getInstance().getImageLoader();
    imageLoader
            .get("http://api.androidhive.info/volley/volley-image.jpg",
                    ImageLoader.getImageListener(imageView,
                            R.drawable.ico_loading, R.drawable.ico_error));

    Cache cache = AppController.getInstance().getRequestQueue().getCache();
    Entry entry = cache
            .get("http://api.androidhive.info/volley/volley-image.jpg");
    if (entry != null) {
        try {
            String data = new String(entry.data, "UTF-8");
            // handle data, like converting it to xml, json, bitmap etc.,
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } else {
    }
```

But on Button click , image View doesn't loads again .

Comment: Your image will not be reload because you save the image url in cache and everytime you get the data from cache not from actual url.

Comment: thanks , But still not reloaded image on click, i remove codes below Cache.

Comment: How did you test that its not reloading? It seems you are trying to load same image, so how did you notice that?

Comment: i am loading image from URL that gives every time new image, like in Capcha. like , https://incometaxindiaefiling.gov.in/e-Filing/CreateCaptcha.do

Comment: Can you please send me the download link for the ImageLoader library

Comment: https://incometaxindiaefiling.gov.in/e-Filing/CreateCaptcha.do

Answer (score 0):

Please clear the ImageView before refresh the images.

Place the below code before setting a new image in Imageview

```
//Add this line
  imageView.setBackground(null);
```

for example,

```
private void makeImageRequest() {

   //Add this line
    imageView.setBackground(null);

    ImageLoader imageLoader = AppController.getInstance().getImageLoader();
imageLoader
            .get("http://api.androidhive.info/volley/volley-image.jpg",
                    ImageLoader.getImageListener(imageView,
                            R.drawable.ico_loading, R.drawable.ico_error));

    Cache cache = AppController.getInstance().getRequestQueue().getCache();
    Entry entry = cache
            .get("http://api.androidhive.info/volley/volley-image.jpg");
    if (entry != null) {
        try {
            String data = new String(entry.data, "UTF-8");
            // handle data, like converting it to xml, json, bitmap etc.,
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } else {
            }
```

Comment: yes , i have remove caching code now . i cleanup project and uninstall App from device. it is not working

Comment: change the loader to picasso. This may help

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [AQuery](http://code.google.com/p/android-query/) for load images in Async and also allowing image cache option :

```
AQuery aq = new AQuery(context);
```

Not allowing image cache :

```
aq.id(imageView).progress(R.drawable.ico_loading).image("http://api.androidhive.info/volley/volley-image.jpg",false,false,0,R.drawable.ico_error);
```

Allowing file and memory image cache :

```
aq.id(imageView).progress(R.drawable.ico_loading).image("http://api.androidhive.info/volley/volley-image.jpg",true,true,0,R.drawable.ico_error);
```

Comment: should i need to add jar files to use AQuery, it is not resolved.